# Prevention of taking screen shot

Tags: swift

I want to prevent taking screenshots while my application is in running mode. I have tried below code but it doesn't work. This observer is called when notification is posted. So how can I detect that user is taking a screenshot or is there any other solution for my problem.Any help would be appreciated.

```
let mainQueue = OperationQueue.main
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshot, object: nil, queue: queue) { (notification) in
            //execution
        }
```

Comment: You cannot stop a user using an operating system feature from within your app. Your app is sandboxed for security and Apple do not like giving you control of operating system features.

Comment: Ok, thank you @Scriptable and Mortiz for answering me. As per Apple's policy, we can not prevent a user from taking screenshots but we can detect that user is about to take a screenshot. Here I have fired UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshot notification but I am unable to detect that. How can I fire that notification when a user takes a screenshot.